# Euler Characteristic of Real Algebraic Surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, real-algebraic-geometry

Given a (compact if needed) real smooth surface $V(f)$ defined by  $f\in \mathbb{R}[X,Y,Z]$, in particular it is oriented. Is there a formula which gives the Euler character of $V(f)$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: That is a hard problem. Suppose $f=P(X)Q(Y)R(Z)$, where $P,Q,R$ are univariate polynomials that are pairwise coprime. Finding  the Euler characteristic  boils down   to finding the number of real roots of each of these polynomials.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Very interesting, could you just explain why the Euler characteristic boils down to finding the number of real roots of each of these polynomials?

Comment: I cannot fix the TeX typo  in my comment above. Take for example the polynomial $$f=P(x)(y^2+1)(z^2+1).$$Then $V(f)$ is a union of planes, one plane  for each real root of $P$. A formula for the Euler characteristic would lead to a formula forthe number of real roots. There are ways of determining this number, Hermite matrix, Sturm sequence, but for higher degrees they are not very practical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A “formula” is a lot to ask for, but there are *algorithms* based on Morse theory.

E.g. §5 of [Basu (1999)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1692627), or §3 of [Fortuna-Gianni-Luminati (2004)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2169368).

Comment: Wow! thank you for the references! I'm impressed by those papers.